# Rails 7: Devise trying to access storage when it has been turned off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, ruby-on-rails-7, devise-jwt

I am trying to use devise without it trying to write to the session store because I am using devise_jwt but no matter how I turn off sessions I keep getting this error:

```bash
ActionDispatch::Request::Session::DisabledSessionError - Your application has sessions disabled. To write to the session you must first configure a session store:
```

Inside `/config/initializers/devise.rb` I have tried this:

```
config.skip_session_storage = %i[http_auth params_auth]
```

But that does not stop the issue. In the `config/environments/development.rb` I have also tried to use this code:

```
config.session_store = :null_store
```

And in `config/application.rb` I have tried this:

```
config.session_store :disabled
```

All of which have not worked

Answer (score 0):

There's a few forums on this. Try updating the config like so. There's several Devise modules you may still be using that rely on cookies/sessions.

```rb
config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
```